# find months from EMI formula if we have given emi,ROI,and priciple amount in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am new Lerner of programming. I have searched every were but but there is nothing for calculate months from EMI formula.
I have try below formula to achieve this.

```
     let ROI:any;

     //PrincipleAmount is total loanAmount

     ROI=(interestRate/100)*PrincipleAmount;
     console.log("NEW RATE OF INTEREST",ROI);

     let x=parseInt(PrincipleAmount)+parseInt(ROI);

     console.log("UpperPart",x);

     let Months:any;

      Months=x/emi;
     console.log("TOTAL MONTHS",Months);
```

and i Also try this too.

```
   let Ipm = P * R / 12 //and find out the interest part
   let monts = P / (EMI-Ipm).
```

but these method will not give me correct result. Is there is any other formula to calulate monts so please help me.

there is one more solution i find but i don't know how to implement it on coding basis.below is method

```
 x = 1 + R

y = EMI / (EMI-PR)

Number of Years = logxy
```

logxy is **log x to the base y** how can is solve log x to the base y in angular

thanks in advance

Comment: Use [`Math.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log)

Comment: I have used that but it will not show the correct months @Suraj Rao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got success in finding Accurate Months from EMI formula as below

```
x = 1 + R

y = EMI / (EMI-PR)

Number of Years = logxy
```

implementing above method i have got correct months.

```
    let R=interestRateCurent/(12*100);
         let X =1+R;
         let z=amount*R;         
         let y1:any;
            y1=emi/(emi-z);

            let logy = Math.log(y1);
            let logx = Math.log(X);         
            let mnths = logy / logx; 
        console.log("Totatal Months:",mnths);
```